# How to limit visibility of a popup menu to all type of files including compilable file like Java file, etc.?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am using `menuContribution`(Command Framework) to show a context menu, I want to limit it's visibility to and only to

1. all type of files whatever in what perspective and view
2. the appropriate editor that has the file open whatever in what perspective and view

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```xml
<menuContribution
            allPopups="true"
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
    <command
        ... >
        <visibleWhen>
            <iterate
                     ifEmpty="false"
                     operator="or">
                <adapt
                     type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                </adapt>
            </iterate>
        </visibleWhen>
    </command>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Java file(and also Groovy file as I tested) and appropriate editor.